# How to convert SQL string date to usable ISO8601 date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I need to check if one date is less than or equal to another. The date is stored in the table as a string in this format `2/1/2020` The SQL Server version on my testing server is 13.0 and the query below works fine but both staging and production is version 11.0.7. Below query is what I have tried so far but get an error

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.".

What is the correct way to write this query so that it works on all of the SQL servers?

````
SELECT TrackingNumber
FROM CarrierTrackingData
WHERE (SUBSTRING(Status, 1, 9) = 'Delivered') AND (CONVERT(date, CAST(DeliveryDate AS date), 23) <= CONVERT(date, CAST(InStoreDate AS date), 23))
GROUP BY TrackingNumber```
````

Comment: What does your date mean?  Jan 2, 2020 or Feb 1, 2020 or something else?

Comment: It means Feb 1, 2020

Comment: "The date is stored in the table as a string" **There's your problem right there.** [Store dates as dates](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type), and never bother yourself again with string representation formats, since [Date and time have no format](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `101` century `mm/dd/yyyy` to convert into date format :

```
WHERE ( SUBSTRING(Status, 1, 9) = 'Delivered' AND 
        CONVERT(date, DeliveryDate , 101) <= CONVERT(date, InStoreDate , 101)
      );
```

Note : You don't need to use `CAST()` as `CONVERT()` with century will do conversation for you.

**EDIT :** You can check the possible date format using `TRY_CONVERT()` :

```
SELECT DeliveryDate, 
       TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DeliveryDate, 101) AS Possible_DeliveryDate, 
       InStoreDate,
       TRY_CONVERT(DATE, InStoreDate , 101) AS  Possible_InStoreDate
FROM table t;
```

`TRY_CONVERT()` will return `NULL` where the conversation fails.

Comment: @FirstElement. . . Then run `DBCC useroptions` to check default date-format.